# Wellposedness of semilinear wave equation with discontinuous source

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

Where can I find existence and uniqueness results for semilinear wave equations with discontinuous, i.e. 
$$\partial^2_{tt} u - \Delta u = f(u), \quad t >0, \ x \in \Omega$$ where $f$ is discontinuous and in $L^\infty$?

If $\Omega$ is bounded, assume Neumann conditions at the boundary. I'd be interested even in only the $1$-dimensional case where $\Omega = [0,1]$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial^2_{tt} u - \partial_{xx}^2 u = f(u),  & t>0, \quad x \in [0,1],\\
u(0,x) = u_0(x), & x \in [0,1], \\
\partial_t u(0,x) = u_1(x), & x \in [0,1], \\
\partial_x u(t,0) = \partial_x u(t,1) = 0, \qquad & t>0.
\end{cases}
$$